# Not able to filter table by Date

Tags: java, date, jtable, tablecellrenderer, datefilter

I made a table editor and I wanted to a filter, where I input a "from" date and a "to" date. All rows that contain the date between those two dates should be displayed, the others are filtered out. My first problem was how to get a date object into the table, without it looking like the standard date object, so I did this:

```
TableCellRenderer tableCellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object 
            newDatum, boolean isSelected,boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (newDatum instanceof Date) {
            newDatum = format.format(newDatum);
        }
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, newDatum, isSelected, 
                hasFocus, row, column);
    }
};
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(tableCellRenderer);
```

But I dont think that the date object stays a date object this way, but Im not sure. The next problem is that, while the code above actually does format the date object into the format "dd.MM.yy", which is what I wanted, once I click on the cell, it immediately turn back to the standard date format.
Also, the filter method I made, Im not sure if it works like this:

```
public void filterDates(Date von, Date bis) {
    List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object, Object>>(2);
    filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, von));
    filters.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE, bis));
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr2 = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(
            (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel());
    table.setRowSorter(tr2);
    tr2.setRowFilter(RowFilter.orFilter(filters));
}
```

I don’t know if it would do what I want, filter the dates between the two given dates.

Now, I dont know if I use the getTableCellRendererComponent method, that uses a tablecellrender, if it stays a date object, if it does, all good. But I need a way to also keep them in my desired format, even if I click on edit the cell.
I have a tablechangeListener, but I dont know what I would have to do.
Right now, if I let the date objects stay in the desired format I want, and use the filter, all rows disappear, if I edit them, so they look like the original date format, and try filtering, they disappear too. Even if the dates are inbetween the two dates I input.

What should happen, is that the date objects stay in the format "dd.MM.yy", even if I click on edit, and I want to be able to filter them inbetween two dates.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: the datefilter of RowFilter wants a date object tho. thats why I need to use it

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: and that means?